# Has anyone managed to get Arduino talking to the CM12U X10 device?

Tags: arduino, x-10

I'm pretty new to the world of Arduino and am trying to get it talking to the CM12U X10 power line interface device. I've seen lots of talk about the US based PSC05/TW523 but nothing for the European CM12U.

I've used the wiring and code found here http://www.arduino.cc/playground/X10/ReceiveX10 and made the suggested changes for 50Hz land, but nothing triggers the receive interrupt.

I've tried reversing the order the pins are connected as there seems to be some confusion as to which way round it should be and that seems to almost continually flood the device - LED13 is on for 14 seconds, then off for 2 seconds & and repeat. (LED13 is lit to show something has been received)

I've triple checked the wiring and continuity tests suggest things are connected ok. (Of course that doesn't help if my assumption that the wiring is the same as the TW523 is wrong!)

Can anyone confirm this device actually works before I dig deeper, or am I'm wasting my time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> LED13 is on for 14 seconds, then off for 2 seconds & and repeat. (LED13 is lit to show something has been received)

Is it located electrically near a switch mode power supply, compact fluorescent or any other device known to generate noise on the power line?  That *could* make it continually receive (noise).

It's an RS232 device so you could hook it to your com port and monitor the transmissions through hyperterm to what is being received.

Comment: Good thinking Joe, I'll look into that. By the sounds of it, if it's an RS232 device, I *should* be able to talk to it as per the original question too.

Comment: It seems Joe inadvertently answered my question with the statement "It's an RS232 device". The code and wiring examples I was using won't work at all because the TW523 X10 device uses TTL. At least I know what to solve next... RS232<->TTL!